# How to show the difference between the opaque reading and the transparent reading via syntax?

Tags: syntax, semantics, syntax-trees, generative-grammar, denotation

Is there any way using any version of Generative Grammar (EST, REST, GB, MP) to show the difference between ["the transparent reading" and "the opaque reading"](http://www.ling.su.se/polopoly_fs/1.20586.1308836031!/menu/standard/file/OnSo_calledSloppyIdentity.pdf#page=10&zoom=auto,-85,567) of the same line using two different trees at the deep structure level?
For example, having:

> John was surprised that the man who won was drunk.

Get a tree that represents the not importance of the description "the man who won" for John's surprise (transparent reading):

> `((man, х) (won х), у) (John z) (surprised that (drunk у), z)`

And another one where description is important (opaque reading):

> `(John, z) (surprised that) ((man, х) (won х), у) (drunk y),z)`

**What would these structures look like for this particular case?** Maybe for transparent one shouldn't be something like mutual c-command relation between nodes with description and "drunk".

Or am I trying in vain to encapsulate the semantic concept of reference in syntax?
If not, is it possible to do the same move with trees for following line?

> The murderer of John is insane.